# Dynamically access to a PropertyInfo whose Type is IEnumerable<customClass>

Tags: c#

I got this code thats works :

```
var assembly= Assembly.LoadFrom("D:\\...\\mydll.dll");
Type rmType = assembly.GetType(specific_class_with_namespace);
bject MyObjj = Activator.CreateInstance(rmType);
PropertyInfo[] pi = rmType.GetProperties();

foreach(PropertyInfo prop in pi)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Prop: {0}",  prop.Name);
}
```

The thing is that the property I wanna access to is a `IEnumerable<IWidget>`, where `IWidget` is an internal class of my dll. So in my current code I can't test the `Type` of my `PropertyInfo` (and cast it right ? :/)
The final objective is to access to the `Name` property of my `IWidget`. Something like :

```
foreach(var widget in myProperty)
{
    string widgetName = widget.Name;
}
```

I read a couple of tutorials on the web and some questions here on SO, but none helped me for my `IEnumerable<customType>` problem :/

EDIT :

when I do :

```
PropertyInfo ItemsProperty = rmType.GetProperty("Items");
var ItemsPropertyValue = ItemsProperty.GetValue(rmType, null);
```

I can a `XamlParseException` with the "most" InnerException being "Object does not match target type"...

Comment: (note that angle brackets *must* be formatted as code to correctly appear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test you property for being of type `IEnumerable` and then in `foreach` loop with `reflection` you can access property of item with name `Name`.

To test for being IEnumerable you can use `typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)` or `type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)`.

EDIT:

In `GetValue` you should put instance not the type:

```
var ItemsPropertyValue = ItemsProperty.GetValue(MyObjj, null);
```

Comment: That's what Im thinking about but when I do : PropertyInfo ItemsProperty = rmType.GetProperty("Items");
            var ItemsPropertyValue = ItemsProperty.GetValue(rmType, null); I can a XamlParseException with the InnerException being   "Object does not match target type"...

Comment: added this to tyhe question !

Comment: `GetValue` if items is declared as `IEnumerable<>` you should cast it to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: But when cast to a Generic type, you have to precise the Type no ?